# How does the entertainment system in aircraft receive moving Map data?

Tags: avionics, inflight-entertainment

How does the in-flight entertainment system inside an aircraft receive data for the moving map, like position, airspeed, origin and destination?

Is it connected to ADS-B receiver or it gets data from on board Avionics System?

Comment: Partially. As no relevant answer as well doesn't have same question related to ADS-B receiver.

Comment: Why would it have anything to do with ADS-B? ADS-B is a broadcast of information which goes from the aircraft to receiver stations on the ground. The aircraft already knows where it is (in order to send the ADS-B); why would they build ADS-B receivers in each seatback? Besides the fact that IFE moving maps have been around since long before ADS-B.

Comment: Not each seat but a single receiver which feeds the avionics , same data can be sent to  IFE.

Comment: The avionics would be fed by physical sensors directly, not ADS-B. ADS-B is not designed for that.